# The probability density of two independent random variable

Tags: probability

I have two independent random variable $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ where,$\delta$ belong to von Mises distribution and $\epsilon$ belong to wrapped cauchy distribution.
I need to find the probablitiy density function of two random variable $\delta$ and $\epsilon$.
my work is product the two probability density of the independent random variable.
if there is theorm in probabilty theory state that ??

Comment: Density of $(\delta,\epsilon)$ is the product of the densities of $\delta$ and $\epsilon$, by independence.

Comment: if there is throrem make sure this ??

Comment: Yes this is a well-known result.